# How to create a DataFrame from a RDD containing list objects?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know if it is possible to create a DataFrame from a JavaRDD that contains Classes with a single List.

E.g. create a dataframe for RDDs containing objects of following class DataRecord:

```
public class DataRecord implements Serializable{

    private List<Object> values;

    public DataRecord(List<Object> values){
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Following the idea (not working)

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd= sc.textFile("hdfs//...").
    .map( new Function<String, DataRecord>(){
        @Override
        public DataRecord call(String line) throws Exception{
              String[] fields = line.split(",");
               List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
                for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
                    values.add(field[i]);
                }
        return new DataRecord(values);
});
DataFrame schemaLogMessages = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, DataRecord.class); //Does not work
schemaLogMessages.registerTempTable("rdd");
DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM rdd");
```

Basically im looking for a generic approach to read any comma separated file and creating a dataframe out of it. So it does not necessarily have to be a list, but since the columns can vary I think that we need a list.

Regards

Comment: Actually, not a single column and the use of csv is also missleading because the columns "vary"

Row1: 2015-10-05 ErrorID=1 testrun=fail
Row2: 2015-10-05 ErrorID=NULL

So I wanted to have a dataframe from a datarecord with a varying list.
However I ended up to filter the dataframes and split it up into distinct ones where each df contains only rows with the same columns.

I think that does it for me.

Comment: Sorry, I actually missed `Object` part. This would require UDT on top of proper getters and setters for DataRecord.